# Yii2 Modify 404 message according to the controller rest api

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I am working on `Yii2` REST API and all APIs are working fine. I just want to know how can I modify `404 error message` according to the controller and their actions.

For example.

I call api `/users/100` and the response, when there is no user with 100 id, is

```
{
"name": "Not Found",
"message": "Object not found: 55554",
"code": 0,
"status": 404,
"type": "yiiwebNotFoundHttpException"
}
```

I have modified this response by the following code in `web.php`

```
 'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                          '<alias:index|about|contact|login|doc>' => 'site/<alias>',
  'users/<id:\d+>' => 'users/',
]
]

'response' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\Response',
            'on beforeSend' => function ($event) {
                $response = $event->sender;

                if ($response->data !== null && Yii::$app->request->get('suppress_response_code')) {
                    $response->data = [
                        'success' => $response->isSuccessful,
                        'data' => $response->data,
                    ];
                    $response->statusCode = 200;
                } else if ($response->statusCode == 404) {
                    $response->data = [
                        'success' => false,
                        'message' => 'Resource not found.',
                    ];
                    $response->statusText = json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Resource not found.']);
                } else if ($response->statusCode == 401) {
                    $response->statusText = json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid key.']);
                }
            },
                    'formatters' => [
                        \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON => [
                            'class' => 'yii\web\JsonResponseFormatter',
                            'prettyPrint' => YII_DEBUG, // use "pretty" output in debug mode
                            'encodeOptions' => JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE,
                        // ...
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
```

But now this is the common message for all 404 errors.

What I want is, If it is for user then the message should be

> No user found

if it is for categories

> No categories found

All these APIs are following the default YII2 REST API standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `yii\rest\ActiveController`, you could simply use a custom `findModel` method (no need to modify response as you did).

In your controller :

```
public function actions()
{
    $actions = parent::actions();

    // customize findModel
    $actions['view']['findModel'] = [$this, 'findModel'];

    return $actions;
}

public function findModel($id)
{
    $model = User::findOne($id);

    if (isset($model )) {
        return $model ;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("No user found");
    }
}
```

EDIT :

`users/sdafsda` is not handled by your user controller, you should fix your url rule : `users/<id>` instead of `users/<id:\d+>`.

Comment: even `findModel` is not calling when we pass string. `users/sdafsda`.

Comment: Just one more question. What if I have two URLs
 ` 'users/<userEmail:[A-Za-z0-9 -_.]+>' => 'users/user-by-email',` AND
               ` 'users/<id>' => 'users/',`

Where first one is for searching by email.